# Constructor of class does not match the argument list....but it does....?

Tags: c++, game-engine, sfml

I'm making a chess engine and using this code:

```
#pragma once

    #include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
    #include "Grid.h"

    enum PieceType { //place gamePieces into Grid not field, cus grid is already in field
        W_BISHOP,
        W_PAWN,
        W_KING,
        W_QUEEN,
        W_ROOK,
        W_KNIGHT,
        B_BISHOP,
        B_PAWN,
        B_KING,
        B_QUEEN,
        B_ROOK,
        B_KNIGHT
    };

class GamePieces //TODO PUT TEAM IN GRID, ACCESS GAME PIECES IN GRID TO MOVE THEM
{
public:
    GamePieces(){}
    GamePieces(PieceType& type, Coords& position) : m_type(type),m_position(position) {
        switch (type) {
            case W_BISHOP:
                m_gamePiece.loadFromFile("w_bishop");
                m_gamePieceSprite.setTexture(m_gamePiece);
                break;

           //REST OF CASES OF PIECETYPE ARE PRETTY MUCH THE SAME

    }
    ~GamePieces();
private:
    sf::Texture m_gamePiece;
    sf::Sprite m_gamePieceSprite;
    Coords m_position;
    PieceType m_type;
};



enum TeamColor {
    BLACK,
    WHITE
};

struct Team {
    //16 pieces in regular chess
    //map that assigns specific game pieces coordinates

    GamePieces m_chessPieces[16];
    TeamColor color;

    Team() {}

    Team(TeamColor& c) {
        Coords coord;

        switch (c) {
            case WHITE: 

                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    coord.m_x += 52.5;
                    coord.m_y += 52.5;
                    m_chessPieces[i] = GamePieces(PieceType::B_PAWN, coord);
                }
                break;
```

Cut out parts I didn't need but basically the error occurs in this line:

```
GamePieces(PieceType::B_PAWN, coord);
```

and it says the constructor of `GamePieces` doesn't have the specified argument list but it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you attempt to assign an rvalue (`PieceType::B_PAWN`) to a non-const reference. The language doesn't allow you to do this.

The solution is to make the constructor take by value or const reference:

```
GamePieces(PieceType type, const Coords& position) //...
```

Answer (score 2):

Temporary cannot bind to non const reference, change your constructor to

```
GamePieces(const PieceType& type, const Coords& position)
```

or

```
GamePieces(PieceType type, const Coords& position)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor takes its arguments by non-const reference, for no reason.

A non-const reference cannot bind to a constant such as `PieceType::B_PAWN`.

You should pass enums by value, unless you want to modify the argument in the called function. You should pass structures such as `Coord` by const reference, or sometimes by value if they're small and simple enough (but by const reference is a safe fallback option).

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to be wrong. Remove the references:

```
GamePieces(PieceType type, Coords position)
```

UPDATE:
Note that the line above is the simplest way to solve the problem. As previous comments says you could take arguments by value or const reference.

In this case, the first one is very small object, so you could take it by value. The second one could be taken by cont reference because it could be larger (8 bytes?). In this sense, the answer by @TartanLlama is perfect.

In spite of that, to take both by value is a good solution because your method is inlined and the compiler has the opportunity to optimize the code (for example, using register instead of the stack to pass arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax:

```
 GamePieces(PieceType::B_PAWN, coord);
```

is not correct. In case of an `enum` variable you don't have to declare the enum type. Correct syntax is following:

```
 GamePieces(B_PAWN, coord);
```

The declaration:

```
GamePieces(PieceType& type, Coords& position)
```

is not correct because you use non-const references. You have to change it to following:

```
GamePieces(const PieceType& type, const Coords& position)
```